# Creating single entity using 2 database table

Tags: java

Sorry for the question but I'm just a beginner in java. I am just wondering if I can create a single entity using 2 tables in the database that is currently existing? If yes, how?

Here's the tables and there respective columns:

Table Name: Book
Table Columns: Header, Title, Subtitle, Details, Image, Booktag

Table Name: Book_dtl
Table Columns: BookSeqNo, Contents, Content_tag, ContSeqNo.

they are joined in BOOK[Header, Title, Subtitle, Details] to BOOK_dtl[BookSeqNo]..

thanks in advance!!

Comment: By entity, you mean using a JPA implementation right?

Comment: You could create a single view using these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read-only entity from two database columns by making a view in your database.  Simply specify the view's name in the `@Table` annotation and then annotate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of doing it
1. by using SQL JOINS
2. by using SQL UNION

You can help yourself out about the syntax of these by doing a quick google search about these.

But if you go for UNION there should be one thing to be cared of,
As we can integrate to select statements using UNION, each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns and the columns must also have similar data types. 
Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Hope It could help you.